# Blocked Ports 5228, 5229, 5230 and many more

Tags: firewall

Ports are blocked by firewall causing me to have no connection on my s5, unless I use a VPN. Please help.   Desperate !!

Comment: Do you have access to the firewall settings? Why do you need these ports? We need more information as you've not provided a clear problem or requested a solution.